# Dynamic list in JQuery mobile getting auto focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am using JQuery Mobile for my Hybrid Mobile Application development. I have a dynamic listView and on render, a random item got focus as shown in the attached image. 
[image]

I inspected the element but couldn't find. How to stop focusing the list item on load ?

Here is my JQuery mobile listview which got rendered in DOM

This is my dynamically created ListView in DOM

```
<ul class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li data-icon="check" answer="0" name="0"><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-check "><img src="" style="display: none;"><p style="font-size: 1em;">Strongly Disagree</p></a></li>
    <li data-icon="check" answer="1" name="1"><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-check "><img src="" style="display: none;"><p style="font-size: 1em;">Disagree</p></a></li>
    <li data-icon="check" answer="2" name="2"><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-check "><img src="" style="display: none;"><p style="font-size: 1em;">Agree</p></a></li>
    <li data-icon="check" answer="3" name="3"><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-check "><img src="" style="display: none;"><p style="font-size: 1em;">Strongly Agree</p></a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the code...

Comment: if you have provided the code then it would have been more easier to solve.